# How to set a Redirect without disclosing location

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-headers

How is it possible to redirect a link without location in header?

See this example:

```
curl -I https://www.ozbargain.com.au/goto/787027
HTTP/2 405 
date: Tue, 11 Jul 2023 01:31:25 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
cache-control: no-cache
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 7e4d496d1db4a865-SYD
```

https://www.ozbargain.com.au/goto/787027

However, it returns a 302 redirect when entered in a browser or redirect checking tool.

This is possibly being done to hide affiliate links from Googlebot.